# Make an http request in Java without modifying global state

Tags: java, http, url, cookies, http-authentication

Suppose I want to make an HTTP request in Java.  I thought I could just do something like `new URL("http://example.com").openConnection()`.  And it seems that for simple things I can indeed do that.  However, I've run into two cases already where I don't know how to that without modifying global state.  If I'm misreading the docs badly, I hope someone corrects me.

1. Suppose I want to use HTTP authentication.  I would expect to be able to use the standard URL syntax for such things: `http://user:pass@example.com`.  This doesn't seem to work and apparently I'm supposed to call `Authenticator.setDefault`.  This is practical if I control all the code in the program, but is totally unsuitable for general-purpose library code.
2. Suppose the site might set a cookie.  By default it will go into a global process-wide cookie jar.  Again, this is rude behavior for a library.  I can change this behavior by calling `CookieHandler.setDefault`, but this again modifies global state.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. You've come across at least one design error in the JRE. I have never understood the `Authenticator` design. You should be able to provide one per `HttpURLConnection`. A global cookie jar on the other hand seems to me to be essential, as cookies outlive connections, by definition.

Comment: Yes, cookies outlive connections.  One way to deal with that is to pass a cookie jar explicitly for each request.

Comment: Deal with what? Cookies are *supposed* to outlive connections. They have no other purpose.

Comment: Yes, cookies are supposed to outlive connections.  That does not mean that cookies must be available to every single HTTP request that the process makes.  Consider the command line tool `curl`.  It takes two command line parameters related to cookies.  (Well, maybe more, but two are relevant to my point.)  In particular, it takes two filenames.  The first file is an already populated cookie jar which contains cookies that should potentially be sent with the current request.  If the remote server tries to set any cookies, they get saved in the second file.  Java could use a similar design.

Comment: Or as another example, take Perl's `HTTP::Tiny`.  It explicitly takes a cookie jar as a parameter.  I'll stop babbling for now though.

Answer (score 1):

1. For basic authentication, you could set authentication header for each request, first base64 encode the `user:password` string and then set the string to request header:

   `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthStr);`
2. For cookies, you could set the cookie policy to ACCEPT_NONE temporarily and get the set-cookie header from the response header, restore the cookie policy, and the use the cookie string:

   `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieStr);`

Comment: You have my up-vote, and perhaps I should accept this answer since it's better than I expected to get.  In fact, for auth, this is a full solution, though needlessly awkward (this should be the library's job!  why should I have to know what needs base64 and what needs percent escapes!?).  But for cookies, this won't do, for two reasons.  The obvious one is: "restore" the old policy how?  I don't know what it was, and have no way to find out.  It may not have been the default one!  The subtle reason is that there is a race condition if someone else makes an HTTP request from another thread.